# Working with Trees in Rx.NET / ReactiveUI

Tags: c#, reactiveui, rx.net

How to observe property changes on any sublevel of a tree?

Consider for example a class `TreeNode` with the properties `Name` and `ChildNodes`. How to observe `Name` changes on any sublevel of a `TreeNode`?

The usage might look something like this:

```
rootNode.FlattenTreeToObservable(x => x.ChildNodes)
        .WhenAnyValue(x => x.Name)
        .Subscribe(...)
```

TreeNode example:

```
// NuGet: Install-Package reactiveui
// In case of Splat version issue: Install-Package Splat -Version 1.6.2
using ReactiveUI; 

public class TreeNode: ReactiveObject 
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this._name; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref this._name, value); }
    }
    private string _name = "";

    public ReactiveList<TreeNode> ChildNodes
    {
        get { return this._childNodes; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref this._childNodes, value); }
    }
    private ReactiveList<TreeNode> _childNodes = new ReactiveList<TreeNode>();
}
```

Comment: Please provide full class definitions of `TreeNode` and any supporting classes. You should make this as easy as possible for us to answer.

Comment: They matter entirely to me. If you can provide concrete classes then you'll get people answering. Otherwise you're asking us to design a system. That's too much in the way of hard work. Like I said, you should make this as easy as possible for us to answer.

Comment: What is `RaiseAndSetIfChanged`? I'm trying to copy, paste, and compile your code.

Comment: It doesn't compile for me. Is there a namespace that I need to add to make it work?

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but `this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged` just isn't compiling. What do I need to do to get it to compile?

Comment: Oh, it must be an extension method on ReactiveUI - there must be a namespace I need to add.

Comment: Please don't delete comments like that. The history of the comments is generally important. It now looks like you haven't responded to me at all. You should only delete comments if you've made a mistake and before others have responded to you.

Comment: Yes, that means don't just keep adding comments. It doesn't mean delete all of the existing ones. And yes, this discussion would help others. It's now confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get your code to run - I ended up with a DLL versioning issue so I wrote a basic class that uses the same structure as yours to get this to work:

```
public class TreeNode
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Subject<TreeNode> ChildNodes { get; }
        = new Subject<TreeNode>();
}
```

I then added the following method:

```
    public IObservable<TreeNode> FlattenTreeToObservable()
    {
        return
            this.ChildNodes
                .SelectMany(cn => cn.FlattenTreeToObservable())
                .StartWith(this);
    }
```

Now when I run this test code:

```
var root = new TreeNode() { Name = "R" };

root.FlattenTreeToObservable().Subscribe(tn => Console.WriteLine(tn.Name));

var a1 = new TreeNode() { Name = "A1" };
root.ChildNodes.OnNext(a1);

var b11 = new TreeNode() { Name = "B11" };
a1.ChildNodes.OnNext(b11);

var b12 = new TreeNode() { Name = "B12" };
a1.ChildNodes.OnNext(b12);

var a2 = new TreeNode() { Name = "A2" };
root.ChildNodes.OnNext(a2);

var b21 = new TreeNode() { Name = "B21" };
a2.ChildNodes.OnNext(b21);

var b22 = new TreeNode() { Name = "B22" };
a2.ChildNodes.OnNext(b22);
```

I get this output:

```
R
A1
B11
B12
A2
B21
B22
```

Comment: That looks great! I wonder if it breaks when you do something like `a1.ChildNodes = ...`. Cannot test right now but will come back to you.

Comment: As for the DLL versioning issue please see the comment about `Splat` in the example.

Comment: @John - No, don't do `a1.ChildNodes = ...`. That will kill it.

Comment: @John - I've edited the answer to avoid the `ChildNodes` re-assignment. If you have to do that then you're going to have to end up doing something tricky with `.Switch()`.

Comment: Will have to try `a1.Name = ...` as well.

Comment: @John - What do you mean by that?

Comment: I'd like to observe `Name` changes on any sublevel of `root`. Your code, however, seems to observe structural changes and simply output `Name`. Imagine wanting to detect name changes in a file tree.

Comment: @John - It should be fairly trivial for you to add a tree flattening property change observable using `FlattenTreeToObservable()` as a guide.